# Eclipse Project Already Exists With This Name

Tags: eclipse

I am using Eclipse Neon x64 on a Win10 system and did not use the installer, rather downloaded the zip file, unzipped to a folder, and ran the exe.  When I ran eclipse the first time, it created a .eclipse folder in my User directory.  Another note, this was a fresh install of Win10.

**The setup:** I created a Dynamic Web Project, the dialog came up and I entered a project name: *Blah*. I then removed the project from the project explorer but did not delete it from disk.  At a later point in time I deleted the Blah project folder directly from the workspace folder.  I tried to create another web project with the same name, but eclipse gave the message: "A project already exists with this name".

I then followed *multiple* SO links on how to clear the project name from different folders under the .metadata folder, from the Navigator, etc., with no effect.  I then escalated this and created a brand new workspace, but still could not add the project with the same name.  I removed every workspace, cleared all working sets, deleted project from Navigator, but still eclipse indicated the a project existed with that name.

I then deleted the eclipse folder with the eclipse .exe, deleted the .eclipse folder in my directory as well as the .p2 folder put there by eclipse, and for all existing workspace folders, remove them or changed the folder names.  So at this point I believe I've removed all breadcrumbs/tentacles of eclipse that I know of.

I unzip the eclipse zip file to a new folder, run the exe, set a new workspace folder.  At the same time I have a file explorer open to this new workspace folder.  After eclipse opens, in the workspace folder it creates a project folder named Blah in which is a .project file.  The creation of this project folder occurs without any prompting on my behalf to create/import a project.

I repeated this multiple times with the same effect.

**The question:**  If I am using eclipse from a zip file, where, other than .eclipse and .p2 folders in my user folder does eclipse maintain any data from which it can resurrect this dead project?  Essentially, I need to cleanse my system of eclipse but cannot find where else it is planting breadcrumbs/tentacles (there should be no tentacles).

Much thanks in advance.

**Update 1**
I deleted everyting in %home%\AppData\Temp, deleted .eclipse and .p2, the eclipse folder and unzipped again.  Same thing - the project is recreated in the new workspace.

Comment: is it a maven project?

Comment: why can't you use the installer to automatically install eclipse?

Comment: It is a "Dynamic Web Project" with the J2EE edition of Neon.  The question is why is the zip file leaving crumbs when I remove everything?

Comment: I tried your scenario locally on Windows without the issue. In any case, that seems more likely to be a bug in Eclipse IDE, or at least a misleading or unhelpful workflow. I suggest you report it to http://bugs.eclipse.org with as much details to reproduce the issue as possible.